# Formatting of grouped bar chart in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, formatting, bar-chart

I am currently stuck on formatting a grouped bar chart.

I have a dataframe, which I would like to visualize:

```
  iteration  position value
1         1   eEP_SRO 20346
2         1 eEP_drift 22410
3         1  eEP_hole 29626
4         2   eEP_SRO 35884
5         2 eEP_drift 39424
6         2  eEP_hole 51491
7         3   eEP_SRO 51516
8         3 eEP_drift 55523
9         3  eEP_hole 74403
```

The position should be shown as color and the value should be represented in the height of the bar.

My code is:

```
fig <- ggplot(df_eEP_Location_plot, aes(fill=position, y=value, x=iteration, order=position)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

which gives me this result:

[image]

I would like to have a correct y-axis labelling and would also like to sort my bars from largest to smallest (ignoring the iteration number). How can I achieve this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please try to share data in a format that is useful, see [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11374827). For R, copy-pasting the output of `dput(your_example_data)` is a preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package to reorder your iterations along the specified values prior to plotting in `ggplot`. See the following with the sample data you've provided:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
iteration <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
position <- factor(rep(c("eEP_SRO","eEP_drift","eEP_hole")))
value <- c(20346,22410,29626,35884,39424,51491,51516,55523,74403)
df_eEP_Location_plot <- data.frame(iteration, position, value)
df_eEP_Location_plot$iteration <- fct_reorder(df_eEP_Location_plot$iteration, 
                                              -df_eEP_Location_plot$value)
fig <- ggplot(df_eEP_Location_plot, aes(y=value, x=iteration, fill=position)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
fig
```

[image: fig]